# Multiline chart, can't get line data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiline-responsive-xbtqzc?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts)

I have a responsive line chart with multi lines from one data source.

The lines also have circles at each data point.

When the page is resized I want to redraw the graph to change the width.

The circles are working but I can't get the same data for the lines.

I'm creating the actual paths but cant seem to add the data to draw the line.

```
const dataLine = d3.line()
  .x((d) => this.x(d.date) + 0.5 * this.x.bandwidth())
  .y((d) => this.y(d.value));

let lines = this.chart.append('g')
  .classed('lines', true)

lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('line-group', true)

let linesUpdate = d3.selectAll('.line-group').selectAll("path") 
  .data(d => d.values)

linesUpdate.enter()  
  .append('path')
  .classed('line', true) 
  .merge(linesUpdate)
  .attr("d", dataLine);
```

How can I add the data to draw the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of D3's data binding process may be a bit counterintuitive: you have to return an array for the `data()` method, that's sure... but then each object in the data array will be treated as an individual data! That's why you see no path, because you're actually appending a dozen paths in that group.

The solution is just wrapping the array inside another array. So turn this...

```
data(d => d.values)
```

... into this:

```
data(d => [d.values])
```

That way, each array will be treated as an individual data point. Then, that data point, which is actually an array of objects, gets passed to the line generator.

Here is your updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiline-responsive-xbtqzc-fldp7c?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts